# How to turn off the hover effect in Expansion Item component in Quasar framework?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

How to turn off the hover effect in Expansion Item component in Quasar framework? And how can I remove the default arrow? I don’t need it at all.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the expansion icon, just give it expand-icon="0". And to remove the hover effect, use CSS to hide the q-focus-helper class.

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <q-expansion-item
      expand-icon="0"
      v-model="expansionState"
    >
      <p>Some content 1</p>
      <p>Some content 2</p>
    </q-expansion-item>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PageIndex',

  data() {
    return {
      expansionState: true,
    };
  },

};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.q-expansion-item {
  .q-focus-helper {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: But the icon is simply hidden. It is still in the DOM. And the css code also doesn't work(

Answer (score -1):

I make it work by setting the css under app.scss, not inside the component itself.

```
.q-expansion-item {
  .q-focus-helper {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```