# How to disable hover color effect in quasar's expansion-item? (Quasar v2)

Tags: css, quasar-framework

How to disable/remove the hover color effect from expansion items in Quasar v2?

Oddly, I can set it to another color, but not to transparent.

```
<template>
    <q-list>
        <q-expansion-item icon="mdi-compass" label="Hello World" class="no-hover-color">
            <q-card> Hello world </q-card>
        </q-expansion-item>
    </q-list>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .no-hover-color:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Related: [How to turn off the hover effect in Expansion Item component in Quasar framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625465/how-to-turn-off-the-hover-effect-in-expansion-item-component-in-quasar-framework) (solution doesn't work, and I suspect is for Quasar v1).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.q-focus-helper {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Codepen

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/JjBZYVq